# error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

When attempting to install drivers for my printer, I get

error: A required dependency 'cups (CUPS - Common Unix Printing System)' is still missing.
error: Installation cannot continue without this dependency.
error: Please manually install this dependency and re-run this installer.

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

try `sudo apt-get install  cups`

Comment: No it didn't work, still get the same error

Comment: Can you please explain what this command does, and why it may solve this problem? While this command is safe, ***it is a TERRIBLE idea to blindly run commands***.